# Transfer the sum of query to label

Tags: mysql, vb.net

the query is working on mysql command line but how can i put the sum to the label

[image]

```vb
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
Try
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String

    Query = "select sum(No_Of_Case_To_Be_Deliver) from ordered= '" & totalcase.Text & "'"

    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
    SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
    MysqlConn.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()

End Try
```

Comment: Your query *is not* valid. You're missing a `FROM` table, and a `WHERE` in front of `ordered`. If `ordered` is your table name, you're missing a `WHERE something = '...'`.

Comment: Also try using parameters instead of the textbox text, to avoid possible sql injections.

Comment: I tried putting from table and where. no error message but the sum is not showing in label

Comment: Can you please post your actual code? The code you have will not compile on its own, so it's hard to know whether the issue is because of something we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Never concatenate strings to build an Sql statement. Use parameters. You are risking damage to your database.

A DataAdapter will open and close its connection for you as part of the `.Fill` method. However, if it finds the connection open it leaves it open.

Glad to see you called `.Dispose` on your connection but you can save yourself the trouble by using `Using...End Using blocks. This will ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Now to the code. You are not Filling or Updating anything so you don't need a `DataAdapter` for this query. You are not Binding anything so no `BindingSource`. Bad name for `DataTable` (dbDataSet) because a `DataSet` is a different type of object. Anyone trying to maintain your code could be easily confused.

By using parameters you not only save yourself from SQL injection but greatly simplify the Sql statement. No worries about double quotes, single quotes, etc.

Since you are retrieving only a single piece of data, you can use `.ExecuteScalar` which returns the first column of the first row of the result set.

I separated the code into a Data Access function and User Interface part. This way you can migrate your application to a different platform, say a web app, by just picking up the function as a whole.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lblTotalCases.Text = DirectCast(GetTotalCases(CInt(totalcase.Text)), String)
End Sub

Private Function GetTotalCases(OrderID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim TotalCases As Integer
    'I made up a query since your query didn't make sense.
    Dim Query = "select sum(No_Of_Case_To_Be_Deliver) from OrderDetails Where OrderID = @ID;"
    Using MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection("Your Connection String")
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = OrderID
            MysqlConn.Open()
            TotalCases = CInt(Command.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return TotalCases
End Function
```

Comment: sorry for the naming, i just watched a tutorial in yt and follow his instructions, your explanation helps me a lot because im still practicing.